# List of all (User defined scalar) functions and their dependencies

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to select a list of all the functions in the database and their dependencies.

(The dependencies that would appear if I were to view the dependencies manually and select the 'Objects that depend on [function]' option.)

My main problem is getting all the dependencies to roll up into one row per function.

I've tried using `stuff`, but for some reason I can't get it to work in this context.

```
select 
    o.name
    , stuff((select N', ' + Name from sys.objects o3 where o3.object_id = o2.object_id for xml path ('')), 1, 1, N'') as Dependencies
from sys.objects o
    left join sys.sql_expression_dependencies sed
    on object_id = referenced_id
    left join sys.objects o2
    on referencing_id = o2.object_id
where o.type='FN' 
order by o.name
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: How many scalar functions do you have? This would be a concern for me because scalar functions are notoriously bad from a performance standpoint.

Comment: There's over 500. I completely agree. I'm cleaning them up, starting with removing most functions which have no dependencies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
SELECT
     O.Name
    ,T.Dependencies
FROM sys.Objects O
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT SUBSTRING(
        (
        SELECT ',' + OBJECT_NAME(D.referenced_id)
        FROM sys.SQL_Expression_Dependencies D
        WHERE D.referencing_id = O.Object_ID
        GROUP BY OBJECT_NAME(D.referenced_id)
        ORDER BY OBJECT_NAME(D.referenced_id)
        FOR XML PATH('')
        )
    ,2,4000) AS Dependencies
) T
WHERE O.Type = 'FN'
ORDER BY O.Name
;
```

If not, update me about what's missing and I can go from there.  Good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for objects that depend on [function]. Rather than objects on which [function] depends. Oddly, I've managed to get this to work using `stuff`, but not the one in question.

Comment: I *almost* asked which direction you wanted it to go, but felt silly... Just goes to show that pride goeth before the guilty query.  Glad you got an answer, at any rate.  Have a good one :)

Comment: I managed to get the desired result by swapping referencing_id with referenced_id. Query is slow but that doesn't matter for my purposes. Any ideas why `outer apply` is needed in this instance?

Comment: It doesn't have to be an `OUTER APPLY` - I did that only because I didn't know if you were going to have results that didn't have a match, or if you wanted to see functions with no dependencies.  You can change it to a `CROSS APPLY`, or even rewrite it as a `JOIN` if you wanted.  It might improve the performance.